# Visual Studio cannot find vcvars64.bat when compiling even though it exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When trying to compile a C++ file in Visual Studio 2019 the compiler gives me this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication4, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Program
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Program': No such file or directory
1>Files
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Files': No such file or directory
1>Microsoft
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '(x86)\Microsoft': No such file or directory
1>Visual
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Visual': No such file or directory
1>vcvars64.bat
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat': No such file or directory
1>ConsoleApplication4.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm assuming that happens because of the spaces causing issues? Any help on how to fix that?

Visual Studio 2019, using the "Local Windows Debugger" for a standard C++ console app. The vcvars64.bat exists.

Comment: Seems an installation failure.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I tried the "repair" option in the VS installer and the same issue arises. Any advice?

Comment: Uninstall completely. Also, why would the compiler call vsvars?

Comment: The windows SDK contains batch files(vcvars64.bat) for setting environment parameters. If you lose this file, maybe you should better reinstall VS.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I uninstalled and installed through the VS Installer and it still gives the same issue.

Comment: You're just using a standard project? You haven't changed any settings? My guess would be a stray quote in one of your environment variables, e.g. `path`

Comment: The compiler thinks that vcvars64.bat is a *source file*.  Clearly that is nonsense, pretty hard to guess why the project is so messed up.

Comment: Okay, I added or edited an environment variable for cl by accident - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019#create-your-own-command-prompt-shortcut - Not sure why, but I deleted that ev. Works now.

Comment: You can write an answer for your question with the details of what you broke and how you fixed it, it might be useful for someone else having the same problem in the future